What is a gauge transformation? How does it relate to Cauchy intial value problem and second functional derivative of the action?
I am having conceptual problems about 'gauge transformation'. I have well heard that gauge trnasformation is a 'local symmetry' and 'fake symmetry', but I want to understand it more precisely.
I am reading Henneaux's , and there are at least 3 points of view of 'gauge transformation' mentioned in this book, and I want to know how are these related to each other:
(1). The Euler-Lagrange equation reads
$$
0 = \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q^n}})
- \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^n}
$$
we can write it equivalently as
$$
\ddot{q^m}\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial \dot{q^m}\partial \dot{q^n}} =
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q^n}
-\dot{q^m}\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial q^m\partial \dot{q^n}}
$$
So given a Cauchy initial data $q^n(t_0)=q^n_0, \dot{q^n}(t_0)=\dot{q^n_0}$, the solution is not unique if
$$
\det(\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial \dot{q^m}\partial \dot{q^n}}) \ne 0
$$
So the gauge transformation refers to 'non-uniqueness of the Euler-Lagrange initial problem'.
(This appears in section 1.1.1 of Henneaux)
(2).
Gauge transformation is a transformation of the $y$'s that (a) leaves the action $S$ invariant and (b) looks like
$$
\delta_\epsilon y^i = R^i_{(0)a}\epsilon^a + R^i_{(1)a}\dot{\epsilon^a} + \cdots + R^i_{(s)a}\frac{d^s\epsilon^a}{dt^s}
$$
where $\epsilon^a(t)$ are arbitrary functions, and $R^i_{(k)a}$ depend on $y^i$ and their time derivatives up to some finite order.
So in this definition, we finally know what a 'local transformation' means.
(This appears in section 3.1.2 of Henneaux)
(3)
Henneaux (3.22) says
$$
\frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta y^m\delta y^n} \xi^m = 0
\Longrightarrow
\xi^i = \lambda^a R^i_{a}
\quad (\text{on } \frac{\delta S}{\delta y_i}=0)
$$
(This appears in section 3.1.11 of Henneaux)
So my question is:
(A) What is the relationship between these 3 definitions of 'gauge transformation'?
(B) How does the arbitrariness in (1) must be of the form in (2)? In this PSE answer it seems that it's not the case.....
(C) How comes (3)?
